# How to get past ImageMagick 7 on Windows 10 error to be compatible with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, imagemagick, windows-10

I am trying to get ImageMagick 7 installed properly with a Windows 10 64 bit computer. I've made sure to download 32 bit versions of ImageMagick so that it is compatible with Rails. I've also added them both to my environment variable and system variable PATHs at the top of the list. When I run `convert -image`
I get `invalid drive specification`

---

I also keep getting this error.

```
        *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
    libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
    need configuration options.



Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
extconf.rb:141:in ``': No such file or directory - identify -version (Errno::ENOENT)
        from extconf.rb:141:in `configure_compile_options'
        from extconf.rb:16:in `initialize'
        from extconf.rb:548:in `new'
        from extconf.rb:548:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/rmagick-2.16.0/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0):

In Imagemagick 7, the syntax is

```
magick inputimage.suffix outputimage.suffix
```

There is no minus sign as per your comment (convert -image)

Sorry, I am not a Windows user to know how to install IM on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it!

1. Download a 32 bit version of ImageMagick
2. When the setup installation Wizard appears, make sure to check the Header files box, AND the legacy code box
3. Look for your download and make sure it has the command exe file available (This is what convert -image needs to run)
4. Add the ImageMagick path to the top of your Environment Variables if it isn't there already
5. Open a command and type in convert -image, it should work now